# How can I count text strings based on adjacent cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a grid of cells in Google Sheets:

A1 displays the quantity of product code **"ABC"** in B1, then C1 displays the quantity of the product code **"DEF"** in D1, it then repeats on the next row for the next customer and so forth.
I am attempting to summarize all of this area at once at the bottom, using some kind of `COUNT` formula, but haven't been able to figure out how yet.

[image: This is an image of one section of what I'm referring to]

Comment: Can you share a sample file?

Comment: Added a link to a snip of what I'm referring to... it's basically just kind of a grid with one column for the quantity and next to it the product, and repeat and repeat.

Comment: I should add that the product column could be any number of different products.... so it could be ABC, or DEF, or XYZ, or the reverse or any other order of many different codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY({A:B;C:D}, 
 "select Col2, sum(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col2
  label sum(Col1)'Sumary', Col2'Item'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I should add that the product column could be any number of different products.... so it could be ABC, or DEF, or XYZ, or the reverse or any other order of many different codes.

Comment: I think I just misread the screenshot... I'm thinking it will work but I just need to adapt the columns to my specific spreadsheet.  I tried attaching a screenshot to your post above with my specific columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({A:B;C:D}, 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2
  label count(Col2)'Count', Col2'Item'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This returns results but I can't make sense of how to alter it for my specific spreadsheet.... I attached a link to a screen shot with columns if that's helpful?

Comment: Okay quick follow up it does work, however the one this is, is there a way to skip a couple rows that are currently used as headers for different sections?

Comment: to skip lets say 3 rows you need to change `{A:B;C:D}` to `{A3:B;C3:D}`. if you have 3 header rows you want to include you just need to add `,3` between `"` and `)` at the end of the formula

Comment: Works perfect thank you!  =QUERY({
F6:G19;H6:I19;J6:K19;L6:M19;N6:O19;
F21:G45;H21:I45;J21:K45;L21:M45;N21:O45;
F47:G64;H47:I64;J47:K64;L47:M64;N47:O64
}, 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col2
  label count(Col2)'Count', Col2'Item'")

Comment: Well, after looking more closely, it seems to work the first time you enter a value, but if you then modify say an amount from "1" to "3", the array function doesn't update...also, with the way I pasted the formula above, it's not actually adding the quantity amount, just counting the occurrence of the contents of the adjacent cell (i.e. 1 ABC and 3 ABC will result in 2 ABC instead of 4).  Is there a way to sum the quantity cell instead of a count function?